# No match for operator with map.find()

Tags: c++, vector, dictionary, iterator

I have a map that's set up like this.

```
vector < map <RGB, int> > count;
```

With an iterator like this:

```
vector < map <RGB, int> >::iterator it;
```

This works:

```
count[min_distance_index].find(img[i]);
```

And this doesn't (it says no match for operator =):

```
it = count[min_distance_index].find(img[i]);
```

Any ideas? RGB is just a struct, and I've defined the < operator myself.

Comment: `std::map::find` doesn't return a `std::vector::iterator`. In fact, I get this from Clang: *error: no viable conversion from 'iterator' (aka '__map_iterator<typename __base::iterator>') to 'std::vector<std::map<int, int> >::iterator' (aka '__wrap_iter<pointer>')* when testing with a `std::map<int, int>` rather than `<RGB, int>`.

Comment: It returns a `std::map<RGB, int>::iterator`

Comment: Alright. Well how would I find something in this sense?

Comment: Use `auto it = count[min_distance_index].find(img[i]);` (C++11)

Comment: That is not "a map". That is a vector of maps.

Comment: Ah okay I understand. Thanks guys. If anyone sees this question later, I had to change the iterator to just a regular map <RGB, int>::iterator.

Comment: @cardinals7879: Then post that as an answer. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code:
`count[min_distance_index].find(img[i]);`
What you do here is:

`vector < map <RGB, int> >[]` which will give you a `map<RGB, int>`
then you call `map<RGB, int>.find()`.
according to this site: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/find/

> An iterator to the element, if an element with specified key is found,
>   or map::end otherwise.
>
> If the map object is const-qualified, the function returns a
>   const_iterator. Otherwise, it returns an iterator.
>
> Member types iterator and const_iterator are bidirectional iterator
>   types pointing to elements (of type value_type). Notice that
>   value_type in map containers is an alias of pair.

`map<RGB, int>.find()` will return you a `map<RGB, int>::iterator`
and not a `vector<map<RGB,int> >::iterator`

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
map<R G B, int> ::const_iterator it;
```

vector[] will return a reference to map

Comment: Look at what he's applying `.find` to.

Comment: count is a vector, but count[min_distance_index] is a reference to map. Is it right?